# TensorFlow, combine two checkpoint values into one and restore

Tags: tensorflow

I have two models (A and B) with the same architecture, both A and B have the same variables names and model settings, for example

```py
['A1\B1\C1', 'A2\B2\C2', 'A3\B3\C3']
```

I have got checkpoint files for A and B, and I want to combine `['A1\B1\C1', 'A2\B2\C2']` in A with `'A3\B3\C3'` in B int to a checkpoint file and restore it to model A. How can I do that with `saver.restor()`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by combine?

Comment: I mean set the values of the later to the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question on my own.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

def load_weights(ckpt_path, prefix_list):
    vars_weights = {}
    reader = pywrap_tensorflow.NewCheckpointReader(ckpt_path)
    var_to_shape_map = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
    for key in sorted(var_to_shape_map):
        for _pref in prefix_list:
            if key.startswith(_pref):
                vars_weights[key+':0'] = reader.get_tensor(key)
    return vars_weights

# Build model
...
# Init variables
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
# Restore model
saver.restore(sess, load_dir_A)

prefix = ['A3\B3\C3']
# Get weights from ckpt of B
B_weights = load_weights(load_dir_B, prefix)
# Assign weights from B to A
assign_ops = [tf.assign(tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(_name, _value) 
                                for _name, _value in opponent_weights.items()]
sess.run(assign_ops)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with init_from_checkpoint. After defining current model, create  assignment map.

```
dir = 'path_to_A_and_B_checkpoint_files'
vars_to_load = [i[0] for i in tf.train.list_variables(dir)]
assignment_map = {variable.op.name: variable for variable in tf.global_variables() if variable.op.name in vars_to_restore}
```

This creates a dict that has variables from current graph as key and variables from checkpoints as values

```
tf.train.init_from_checkpoint(dir, assignment_map)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  #do_usual_stuff
```

This function is placed before declaring a session and substitutes `saver.restore`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got model weights files for A and B. I want to set values in `'A3\B3\C3'` of B to values in `'A3\B3\C3'` of A and restore the modified model weight file of A. Your code `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` can reset weights of the model to be some random initial values.  `assignment_map = {variable.op.name: variable for variable in tf.global_variables() if variable.op.name in vars_to_restore}` I think it can only restore `'A3\B3\C3'` of B in my case. Could you please check it?

Comment: `init_from_checkpoint` overrides standard initializer, so that won't be a problem. As for particular variables, I think you're right. Maybe you'll have to define assignment map manually in order to match all the variables you need in particular order. I'll see what can be done

Comment: Hi, thank you. I found this function https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py#L32 can help me to extract the variable name and weights, however, I found the names returned were different. I asked a new question on this with my code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55350578/tensor-names-in-checkpoint-are-different-from-tf-get-collectiontf-graphkeys-tra