# Tensor names in checkpoint are different from tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)

Tags: tensorflow

I wrote my code to extract weights to assign values to some tensors in my model.

```py
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow

vars_weights = {}
reader = pywrap_tensorflow.NewCheckpointReader(file_name)
var_to_shape_map = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
for key in sorted(var_to_shape_map):
    vars_weights[key] = reader.get_tensor(key)
```

However, the `key`s are something like this

```
'm_0/net_1/dense_2/kernel/Adam'
'm_0/net_1/dense/bias/Adam'
'm_1/net_1/dense_2/bias/Adam'
```

However, Tensor names returned from 
 `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)` are different from names above.

```
'm_0/net_1/dense_2/kernel/Adam:0'
'm_0/net_1/dense/bias/Adam:0'
'm_1/net_1/dense_2/bias/Adam:0'
```

It returned the real name of tensors. How can I fix it by returning the real name of tensors in my code?

Comment: If i got you right, this should not be a problem, it's just naming

Comment: @Sharky thank you. But it really confused me. If the indexing number is not 0, it is not easy to assign the weights to the network and it is hard to detect it.

Comment: Inde will look like `_1`